# PHP POST data in header() function

Tags: php, forms, variables, redirect, post

I have a form that requires all information to be filled out and I have the script that checks to see if the fields are filled in, but I am unable to figure out how to get it to redirect back to the form with POST data to explain the error, is there such a way to do this????

I know it's possible to do this with GET data like so `header("Location: index.php?e=1");`
but I want to have the URL simply say:

`https://foo.bar/index.php` instead of `https://foo.bar/index.php?e=1`

Comment: I believe it is impossible to redirect with a POST request. The resulting request will always be a get request and any post data that was send to the first url will not be send to the second url.

Comment: The browser won't allow this because POST should be sent to the location the user is aware of. Forwarding POST data is seen as a sort of break in the post data 'chain of custody'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you HTML you could write code like this :

```
<input name="name" value="<? echo isset($_POST['name'])? $_POST['name']:"default_value";?>">

//Expecting you submission would be on same page where your have written your HTML content.
```